# Spring @Transactional annotation when using try catch block

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

If we catch the exception in method annotated with the `@Transactional` annotation, will it roll back if any exception occurs?

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Throwable.class)
public void yearEndProcess() {
    try {
        // try block
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        // catch block
    }
}
```

Comment: try it in your applcation, i assume you understand what does `@Transactional` do.

Comment: @user3404577 Can you show us your snippet code?

Comment: @user3404577 Where is contained **yearEndProcess** method? The class that contains yearEndProcess is a Service,Component or other adn finally implement some interfaces?

Comment: calling this method from controller. And i just want to know that if i rollback transaction programmatically as mentioned by ker p pag, then will that company update work?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

for example

```
class A{
    
    @Transactional
    public Result doStuff(){
        Result res = null;
        try {
          // do stuff 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
        }
        return res ;
    }
}
```

If there is an exception in the method `doStuff` the **transaction isn't rolled back.**

`To rollback the exception programmatically`, we can do something like below.

**declarative approach**

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor={MyException1.class, MyException2.class, ....})
public Result doStuff(){
   ...
}
```

**programmatic rollback**

you need to call it from `TransactionAspectSupport`.

```
    public Result doStuff(){
      try {
        // business logic...
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        // trigger rollback programmatically
        TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
      }
    }
```

You are strongly encouraged to use the `declarative approach` to `rollback` if at all possible.
`Programmatic rollback` is available should only be used if you absolutely need it.

Comment: I am calling this method "yearendprocess" from some other method of the same object. Which is also annotated with @transactional annotation. Would it work that way ?

Comment: @ankur-singhal, I don't understand why we need `@Transactional(rollbackFor={MyException1.class, MyException2.class, ....})`? The default `rollbackFor` is `Throwable`, it should already covered it?

Comment: This is not always true. A rollback would still happen here if an insert or update failed (even if surrounded by try/catch). This is because when Spring Boot detects a DB error, it marks the transaction as `rollBackOnly` regardless if the Exception is caught or not

Comment: @Ankur Any chance of comment on similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77256992/how-to-catch-check-for-uniqueness-in-spring-boot-3

Answer (score 3):

**From spring references documentation**

Spring recommends that you only annotate concrete classes (and methods of concrete classes)
with the @Transactional annotation, as opposed to annotating interfaces. You certainly can
place the @Transactional annotation on an interface (or an interface method), but this works
only as you would expect it to if you are using interface-based proxies. The fact that Java
annotations are not inherited from interfaces means that if you are using class-based proxies
( proxy-target-class="true") or the weaving-based aspect ( mode="aspectj"), then
the transaction settings are not recognized by the proxying and weaving infrastructure, and the
object will not be wrapped in a transactional proxy, which would be decidedly bad.

In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are
intercepted. This means that self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling
another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the
invoked method is marked with @Transactional.

Then with @Transaction the default behavior is that any RuntimeException triggers rollback, and any checked Exception does not. Then  your transaction roll back for all RuntimeException an for the checked Exception Throwable

Answer (score 2):

you would want to read [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html)

**Integrated transaction management**. You can wrap your ORM code with a declarative, aspect-oriented programming (AOP) style method interceptor either through the @Transactional annotation or by explicitly configuring the transaction AOP advice in an XML configuration file. In both cases, transaction semantics and exception handling (rollback, and so on) are handled for you. As discussed below, in Resource and transaction management, you can also swap various transaction managers, without affecting your ORM-related code. For example, you can swap between local transactions and JTA, with the same full services (such as declarative transactions) available in both scenarios. Additionally, JDBC-related code can fully integrate transactionally with the code you use to do ORM. This is useful for data access that is not suitable for ORM, such as batch processing and BLOB streaming, which still need to share common transactions with ORM operations.

Answer (score 0):

You have already mentioned attribute:rollbackFor=Throwable.class in your @Transactional annotation.

So, for any kind of exception transaction will be rolled back.

Comment: RuntimeException

Answer (score 0):

The transaction will only be rollback iff a runtime exception is thrown out of your method which is annotated as @Transactional

Comment: similar question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77256992/how-to-catch-check-for-uniqueness-in-spring-boot-3