# Using the Current Sesssion after an exception is thrown

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, bulkinsert

According to [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-exceptions) it is unsafe to use the Session after an exception is thrown by Hibernate.

> If the Session throws an exception, including any SQLException, immediately rollback the database transaction, call Session.close() and discard the Session instance. Certain methods of Session will not leave the session in a consistent state. No exception thrown by Hibernate can be treated as recoverable. Ensure that the Session will be closed by calling close() in a finally block.

In my code I am doing a batch insert. I am using `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` method to obtain the session. My code is like this.

```
try {
  //some code here....
  ....
  Table1Entity table1Entity = .......
  List<Table2Entity> table2Entities = .......
  Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  for (int i = 0; i < table2Entities; i++) {
      .............
      currentSession.save(table2Entities.get(i));
      if(i % batchSize == 0 || i + 1 == table2Entities) {
        currentSession.flush();
        currentSession.clear();
    }
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
    currentSession.getTransaction().rollback();
    //currentSession.close(); //According to documentation Session should be closed here
    table1Entity.setError(true);
    currentSession.save(table1Entity);//According to documentation Session should not be used here
    .......
}
```

As documentation says the session should not be used after an exception is thrown. My problem is since I am using the `currentSession`, how can I save the `table1Entity` in catch block? Should I open a new session using `openSession()` method or any other way?

---

**Edit:** To be more clear simply what I am asking is whether I could retrieve a new **currentSession** after the existing **currentSession** is closed.

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738883/spring-transactional-annotation-when-using-try-catch-block/25739582#25739582) helps you somewhere

Comment: @ankur-singhal Thanks for the link. But it doesn't solve my problem. In that answer he rollsback the whole transaction. In my case I need to persist another entity after an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It is a single try..catch block. How can you be certain that the Hibernate exception will definitely not be thrown from whatever processing is done on table1Entity? If the exception does arise while processing table1Entity, then trying to save that in the current session could create greater problems.

My advice would be that you separate the processing on the tables into separate try..catch blocks and call save separately in each block. After an exception is thrown, attempting to save a transaction in the same session within a catch block is unsafe and assuming that there is no issue in table1Entity can be counter-intuitive sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Above code is not from my actual class. Anyway as I see you haven't understood my question. As the documentation says if Hibernate threw an exception when saving table2Entities, the session should no longer be used for future transactions. The Session.close() should be called and Session instance should be discarded. What my question is after I closed the session how can I retrieve a new Session to save table1Entity?

Comment: Why don't you just save table1Entity before going on to table2Entities?  Because from what understood, you want table1Entity to be persisted even if something fails whiile processing table2Entities. That is what I have suggested in my answer too.

Comment: No, actualy I want to call the setError() method of table1Entity and save it only if an exception is thrown when saving table2Entities. Please see my code above.

Comment: If I were you, I'd rethink my implementation. Persisting data using a 'dirty' session can have unpredictable consequences. Consider the alternate approach where you save table1Entity data, and continue processing table2Entities. If no exception is thrown, then delete the saved table1Entity data after the table2Entities data is stored, otherwise handle the exception and the table1Entity is saved. In this approach, there is no data persistence done with the session after an exception has been thrown.

Comment: @CodeNewbie That last comment of yours is quite a good idea basically but has the downside that you can't write any error messages with it (as they have not appeared yet).

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against writing to a database in case of an exception in the connection to that database. So basically, I think you approach has severe problems and fixing it will most likely don't do you any good.

In situations like this you should take great care that your batch won't throw an exception, no matter what. So, if an exception does occur, you can assume that the database is unreachable or otherwise won't accept any attempts anyway. Write the error to some other place (log files have proved to be useful for this).

I can see situations where it seems that your approach is a viable one (like I update all the ones that work, the others I mark. To recognize the "others" I use an exception) but it next to never is in fact a good idea but instead a situation of "being witty". - Don't be witty, it won't pay off.

Instead write your batch in a way that the ones that won't work out as preferred instead return a proper result that says "I didn't work" and handle that appropriately.

So in your case:

```
try {
  //some code here....
  ....
  Table1Entity table1Entity = .......
  List<Table2Entity> table2Entities = .......
  Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  for (int i = 0; i < table2Entities; i++) {
      .............

      // HERE you need to make sure that this call would succeed
      currentSession.save(table2Entities.get(i));
      if(i % batchSize == 0 || i + 1 == table2Entities) {
        currentSession.flush();
        currentSession.clear();
    }
  }
  currentSession.save(table1Entity);
  currentSession.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
  currentSession.getTransaction().rollback();
  log.warn("Could not do what I wanted", e);
}
```

That either works out whole or not at all and gives you a proper stack trace with messages and all in the place where it belongs (the log).

Maybe you want to probe if a call would succeed before doing it.

If you think you must do what you want, read the comments of CodeNewbie under his answer: Create the table1Entry with `setGoingToWriteBatch(true)` then in the end of the batch `setBatchWritten(true)`. That way you can locate the ones where the first one is true, but the second one not.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. Basically my batch fails if a duplicate ID value found in DB. In such case I want to rollback all the inserts of the table2Entities and fill the 'error' column of table1(table1Entity) with 'true'. Can you suggest me how can I set this property of table1Entity to true after failing the batch and save it to DB. Thanks.

Comment: I actually don't believe that CodeNewbies suggestion of inserting and deleting Table1 record is good. For an example when I am using sequences it calles nextVal(), then assign an ID, then if an exception thrown that ID is deleted. So that ID can never be used. On the other side I am using a large batch which takes some time to get inserted. So while my batch is still being inserted, if anybody queried the Table1, he sees that the column 'Error' has been set to 'true'. This is misleading. Rather than using that solution I prefer to avoid using getCurrentSession() and use openSession() instead.

Comment: @prageeth how to do this very much depends on how you do it now. I usually use SQL for this kind of stuff as it gives you more direct control (and is faster) over whats happening, rather than using the Object oriented wrapping around it. But if you want to stick with OO approach just do a select before insert.

Comment: @prageeth I think the idea of inserting and deleting is no good either but the principle - write something first and something different on success instead of failure is good. Write property1 beforehand and if property2 never gets set you know its broken. But don't write on Exception, thats just bound to break.

Comment: @prageeth One thing: Sequences are meant for this specific reason. If you miss one (or a thousand) it should never matter at all in any way! That ID will never be used and that is a fine thing - don't work around this. If you need a sequence that has no missing numbers at all (like a invoice number) you should insert the invoice with a different ID field. Then after inserting the invoice succeeded, you update it to contain the next invoicenumber. I'm quite certain that your real problem is at avoiding that overlapping id. You should ask yourself (and google) why you do it that way.

Comment: I am reading values from a large xls file. End user enters data in to the excel file and uploads the file. What my app does is saving those records in to DB. Having a duplicate record in excel file is very rear in my case. So I dont need to do a whole DB check before start inserting my batch. What I do is if a duplicate found catch the exception and insert the batch one by one. I know I can do this with openSession() method cleanly instead of using getCurrentSession() where I have all the transaction handling, session handling under my control. Anyway thank you @Angelo.

Comment: @prageeth Or you could remember in a List the entries that were already there (or at least the identifying elements of it) and skip the second appearances.