# grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional not rolling back

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, integration-testing, grails-orm

I am having issues rolling back a transaction in my service layer with the following:

Grails 3.3.8

GORM 6.1.10.RELEASE

I have the following service method:

```
import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional

@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
class TestingService {

    void testServiceMethod(List<Factory> factories) {
        try {
            factories.each {
                if (it.name == 'second') {
                    throw new Exception('second')
                }
                it.testField = 'Edited'
                it.save()
                println(it.name + ' saved')
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            println('Exception Caught ' + e)
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following integration test created then also:

```
@Integration
@Rollback
class TestServiceIntSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    TestingService testingService

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test something"() {
        when:
        Factory factoryOne = new Factory(name: "first").save(flush: true)
        Factory factoryTwo = new Factory(name: "second").save(flush: true)
        List<Factory> factories = [factoryOne, factoryTwo]
        testingService.testServiceMethod(factories)

        then:
        factoryOne.testField == null
        factoryTwo.testField == null
    }
}
```

I also have the following controller method:

```
class TestController {

    TestingService testingService

    def index() {
        Factory factoryOne = new Factory(name: "first").save(flush: true)
        Factory factoryTwo = new Factory(name: "second").save(flush: true)
        List<Factory> factories = [factoryOne, factoryTwo]
        testingService.testServiceMethod(factories)
        println "First Factory: $factoryOne.testField"
        println "First Factory: $factoryTwo.testField"
        render 'Check Console'
    }
}
```

I would have expected the test to pass as I thought the transaction would of rolled back after I threw new exception, the it.testField is persisting though however? Also when I ping the TestController it is outputting factoryOne.testField as 'edited'. Am I misunderstanding this correctly from the documentation?

"Services enable transaction demarcation, which is a declarative way of defining which methods are to be made transactional. To enable transactions on a service use the Transactional transform:
The result is that all methods are wrapped in a transaction and automatic rollback occurs if a method throws an exception (both Checked or Runtime exceptions) or an Error."

Source: https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/services.html#declarativeTransactions

I can't see what I'm doing different from this other Stackoverflow answer either:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25739582/6887293

The issue can be recreated by pulling the following Github project and running /factory/factory/src/integration-test/groovy/com/mycompany/myapp/TestServiceIntSpec.groovy or pinging /factory/factory/grails-app/controllers/com/mycompany/myapp/TestController.groovy

https://github.com/georgy3k/IntegrationTestRollBack/tree/8addd2b95a8ffa4570e70eccb3b023b0ccfef5aa

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

In your catch block you need to re-throw the exception.

```
catch (Exception e) {
        println('Exception Caught ' + e)
        throw e;
}
```

The problem as i see it, is that the exception never escapes the method.