# @Transactional Does the catch exception continue to be thrown after the rollback

Tags: java

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = {
    Exception.class,
    RuntimeException.class
})
public void parent() {
    try {
        child();
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        //i want do something at here, how to catch the child RuntimeException 
        //child Transactional cath RuntimeException，can i catch it here？
    }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY, rollbackFor = {
    Exception.class,
    RuntimeException.class
})
public void child() {
    try {
        xxxMapper.update();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("false");
    }
}
```

the child Transactional catch the RuntimeException and rollback

I call child in parent, can I catch this RuntimeException?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring @Transactional annotation when using try catch block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738883/spring-transactional-annotation-when-using-try-catch-block)

Comment: I want cache the child RuntimeException in parent, what should I do?Is my code right?

Comment: https://www.codetreasury.com/2014/01/25/springs-transactional-important-points/ => point nr 2

Comment: it's helpful，thank you。